# Do I need mongo db/xDb license to set xDb.TrackingEnabled = true?

Tags: mongodb, tracking, geo-location

We use Sitecore 8.2 update 3 and we do not have xDB license and mongo db, however in one of the modules we need to use geo IP which requires having xDB.TrackingEnabled = true. 
Can this be achieved without mongo and what are the implications of removing tracking Connection Strings? I cannot find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the information here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker

> When Xdb.Tracking.Enabled is set to true and have xDB disabled:
>
> - Contacts cannot be identified immediately, and any data gathered from    the contact is discarded at the end of the session.
> - You can use personalization rules for contact facets and segmentation.
> - IP Geolocation services are available.
> - Engagement plan processing occurs for the live session.
> - Contact repositories are available for the session, and outcomes that are triggered during the session are registered.

So: You don't need the xdb connection strings (to mongo). You don't need Mongo databases or a xdb license. You should disable xdb and enable tracking. That way you can use GeoIP.

Comment: I saw this article but the question was actually about the tracking mongo dbs: <add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/Sitecore_tracking_live"/>
  <add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/Sitecore_tracking_history"/>
  <add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/Sitecore_tracking_contact"/>. What is the implication of not having these databases?

Comment: In your case: none. When xdb is not enabled, you don't need the Mongo databases.